# Why Oracle is not recognizing this date format?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g, timestamp

I am trying to convert a timestamp into date, but the following is not working.

```
select to_date('28-06-21 23:53:58.123', 'dd-MM-yy HH24:MI:SS.FF') from dual;
```

It says that the date format is not recognized. The problem is caused by the sub-seconds part, as the following works.

```
select to_date('28-06-21 23:53:58', 'dd-MM-yy HH24:MI:SS') from dual;
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: [For each DATE value, Oracle stores the following information: year, month, day, hour, minute, and second.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-5405B652-C30E-4F4F-9D33-9A4CB2110F1B)

Comment: to_date creates a DATE.   A DATE does not include fractional seconds.  Therefore, to_date data mask makes no provision for fractional seconds.  TIMESTAMP does include fractional seconds.  If you want to convert TIMESTAMP to DATE, you will have to drop the fractional seconds.

Comment: I solved it by using the following, SELECT TO_DATE(CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP('28-06-21 23:53:58.123', 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS.FF') AS DATE)) FROM dual

Comment: @MetallicPriest `to_date` converts a string to a date. Your `cast(... as date)` already returns a date, so you don't need to convert it again. In fact, using `to_date` on a date implicitly forces Oracle to first convert it to a string, but doesn't tell it how, so it has to rely on the `nls_date_format` and NLS language settings, which can have unexpected results.